# How to put each points in each bar

Tags: matlab, histogram

I would like to do a 2d histogram (using hist3), where each of my points that have the same x but not the same y, to be only in one bar. So inside each bar of the histogram I would like to have only the points that they have the same x but not the same ye. So in this case even if i change the bin size, i will have again inside a bar, the same number of points. Can someone help me to do it?

Comment: If i understand your sentence " I would like to have only the points that they have the same x and y," correctly you don't want to plot all data but only those who have the same x and y value(or at least bin). That would result in a 2dhistogram which would have entries only on the diagonal. Thus it could be reshaped to a 1dhist which would have as an entry those diagonal elements. Is that really what you want? If not pls try to explain your situation and your wanted result better/Clearer.

Comment: Oh no, I would like to have all my data, but not in a bar to have different points, that have different x. So, they should have the same x (I did a mistake before), but all the same x

Comment: ok that is different. So you require the x to be the same but the y can vary. is that it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, x the same and y vary

Answer (score 1):

this? Choose option 1 for same x and y. choose option 2 for same x but y can vary

```
%simulation
x=1:10;
y=1:10;
figure,

%code to be used
ctrs{1}=unique(x); % same x in each bar

%option 1
ctrs{2}=unique(y); % same y in each bar

%option 2
bins=10; % y bins from min to max
ctrs{2}=linspace(min(y),max(y),bins); % y bins from min to max

hist3([x;y]',ctrs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift answer. It seems that for this example it is working.

Comment: But I have a lot of data, around 12.000 and is giving me this error:??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> repmat at 92
            B = A(mind,nind);

Error in ==> hist3 at 253
xx = repmat(xx,1,nbins(2));

Comment: the problem may be because you require the data to be in each bar to be exactly equal. you should allow some error

Comment: Thank you again. Now it seems working, but I can not see any bar in my plot, it is just a plan with different colors. Do you have any idea what it can be the problem?

Comment: In this way, all my bars are in the same level, so the altitide is the same for all, and it is 1. What can I do to have the real altitude for each bar?